# Custom equality between classes

Tags: scala, oop, equality

I'm currently learning Scala and haven't programmed much the last few years, so I may have forgot some OOP fundamentals.

I'm trying to implement the two classes:

```
case class Rectangle(a : Int,b : Int) extends Shape
case class Square(a : Int) extends Shape
```

The trait/abstract class (I tried both, neither works) `Shape` is defined as follows:

```
trait Shape {
  def a : Double
  def b : Double 
  def area = a *b
  def sides = 4
  def perimeter = 2 * (a+b)

  def equals(r: Shape){
    r.a == this.a && r.b == this.b
  } 
}
```

The desired behavior is `Rectangle(2,2) == Square(2)`

I thought it should work like this as the operator `==` should use the `equals` method which I expect to use the most specific implementation (default implementation when called with some random class and my implementation when called with another `Shape` as argument.

So, my questions are:

- How could this be implemented?
- Is there a reason this should not be implemented (e.g. it is in conflict with some OOP principles, though it would be transitive, reflexive and symmetric)
- Should Shape be an abstract class or a trait?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overriding `equals` method, you need to overload `==` operator in `Shape`.

Please see below for more information about operator overloading.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/operators.html

Edit:

Apparently, my initial answer was not clear enough. See sample below:

```
  abstract class Shape(val a: Int, val b: Int) {
    def ==(other: Shape): Boolean = this.a == other.a && this.b == other.b
  }

  class Square(s: Int) extends Shape(s, s)
  class Rectangle(x: Int, y: Int) extends Shape(x, y)

  def main (args: Array[String] ): Unit = {
    println(new Square(2) == new Rectangle(2, 2))  // true
    println(new Square(2) == new Rectangle(4, 2))  // false
    println(new Square(2).equals(new Rectangle(4, 1))) // false
  }
```

Comment: I think this is just plain wrong. Everything I've found states that "==" falls back on the `equals(x : Any)` method. Your link also does not contain anything relevant to the question(s) asked.

Comment: Indeed, it seems to work. Though slide #10 here https://www.slideshare.net/knoldus/object-equality-inscala seems to advise against doing this. 

Also I've changed your method to reflect the equality intended in the question.

Comment: @oerpli as the slides states, this is a discouraged feature, because it makes code hard to read. I have tried to show you the way to do it. Instead of overriding `==` operator, I suggest you to create another method like "compare" etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this set of slides that solved the problem (and at least answers the 1st of my questions): https://www.slideshare.net/knoldus/object-equality-inscala (p9)

The problem seems to be that it's necessary to override the built-in equals method and not only adding an additional overload.

```
override def equals(other : Any) : Boolean = other match{
  case s: Shape => s.a == this.a && s.b == this.b
  case _ => false
}
```

In my tests so far this works as desired.

On slide 13 it mentions that "equals" should only return true, if their hashcodes are also identical (which is not the case).

Comment: Remember to override hashcode as well if when you override equals so that they remain consistent.